# UK Skilled Worker Visa: Resign prior to completion of minimum employment period

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, employment, immigration

##### Context

X is on Skilled Worker Visa.
X's employment contract states

- 2 year minimum employment period
- 3 month minimum notice period after serving the minimum employment period.

### Question

Given the above context, is it possible for X to resign from their current employment prior to serving the minimum 2 year employment period?

Follow-up questions:

- What are the legal implications of doing that?
- Is it legally possible?
- Can the employer refuse the resignation? What to do in such a case?
- Are there legal proceedings involved?

Comment: Slavery was abolished a long time ago...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a minimum two year *contract*? And what is the notice period *before* the minimum term? If it is not stated, it is the statutory notice period (one week).

Comment: Are you sure the 2 years and +3 months doesn't refer to the visa conditions, as opposed to the contract of employment?

Comment: @WeatherVane what is meant by min 2 year _contract_ ? How is _contract_ different from 2 year _period_ ? On the employment contract atleast, it says minimum employment period = 2 years.

Comment: A two year minimum contract says nothing about the period of notice, but a two year minimum period suggests it. What does the contract actually say about notice required during the first two years?

Comment: @Rick it's not related to Visa condition as the SW Visa is for 3 years.

Comment: @WeatherVane contract doesn't say anything about notice required during the first 2 years. Quoting the contract: _"The minimum period of employment is 2 years. After the successful completion of your 2 year, you will be able to leave your role with a written 3-month notice. If your employment is terminated by the Practice, you will be entitled to 3-month notice. By mutual agreement, this notice period can be waived"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to prevent an employee resigning before the end of a fixed-term contract of employment.

But note that there may be legal implications if **X**'s conditions of entry and leave to remain in the UK are not complied with - see, for example, [Section 9.27.1 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal) which includes:

> 9.27.1. A person’s entry clearance or permission on the Skilled Worker [ ... ] routes may be cancelled if:
>
> - (d) they cease to work for their sponsor.

There's not much more to say as the question lacks detail, such as whether **X** has another job offer, intends to leave the UK, or apply for another visa, etc. Or whether the references to 2 years and +3 months actually applies to the visa conditions, not the contract of employment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. X is under the process of switching from Skilled Worker Visa to Skilled Worker Dependent visa. Does that complicate things a bit?

Comment: just to clarify, it is not a fixed-term contract, in the sense that there's no limit mentioned in the employment contract. Does your sentence - _There is nothing to prevent an employee resigning_ still hold true for permanent contract or one which doesn't have a fixed end-date?